# Codeception\Exception\TestParseException Couldn't parse test

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, codeception

Here is my codeception version 
Codeception version 2.2.1

```
codecept bootstrap
```

Then I generate test, just like in the QuickStart Guide  http://codeception.com/quickstart

```
codecept generate:cept acceptance Welcome
```

I started my server on localhost:9000

```
codecept run -vvv
```

...gives me the error:

> [Codeception\Exception\TestParseException]   Couldn't parse test
>   'D:\OpenServer\domains\codeception-demo\tests\acceptance\WelcomeCept.php'
>   No syntax errors detected in
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\codeception-demo\tests\acceptance\WelcomeCept.php

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It happened because
`php -l D:\OpenServer\domains\codeception-demo\tests\acceptance\WelcomeCept.php` returned non-zero status code.

Code linting can be disabled in codeception.yml:

```
settings:
  lint: false
```